# UItextview resize height for all devices with Keyboard Swift

Tags: swift, swift3, uitextview, uitoolbar, uikeyboard

I have one UIToolBar in top of Keyboard here is my code

```
extension UIViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func addToolBar(textField: UITextField) {
        let toolBar = UIToolbar()
        toolBar.barStyle = .default
        toolBar.isTranslucent = true
        toolBar.tintColor = UIColor(red: 76 / 255, green: 217 / 255, blue: 100 / 255, alpha: 1)
        let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(donePressed))
        let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(cancelPressed))
        let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        toolBar.setItems([cancelButton, spaceButton, doneButton], animated: false)


        toolBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        toolBar.sizeToFit()

        textField.delegate = self
        textField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
    }
```

I have one UITextview in Storyboard, and I want to resize the UITextView **height** with **Y=0** so it fits in Toolbar for all devices. I know the uitoolbar it's 44 **height**. Does anyone know how can I do this?